# grammar rules for titles of posts

Tags: grammar

When referring to America, one should use the definite article, "the", "the United States".

However, in some titles of posts, the definite article is omitted.

[image]

[image]

Is that some kind of grammar rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. In general, we should absolutely use 'the' to say 'The United States of America'.

The examples you show use 'headline style grammar'. I would say this is more of a style than a rule. Since headlines need to be short, some ellipsis (omission of words) is used.

This ellipsis is often applied to:

- Articles
- The verb 'be'

So, the phrase:

> The United States Presidential Election was held recently

could be transformed into 'headline style' like so:

> United States Presidential Election held recently

More formally, this style is referred to as Headlinese. You can read more about it (there is more to it than just ellipsis) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).